Problema con tooltips y un contenedor que las corta, no encuentro cómo resolverlo
espero estén muy bien.
Mi situación es la siguiente, tengo un contenedor con un botón ver más, ver menos, necesito agregar unas tooltips, pero cuando lo hago, estas se cortan a la altura del contenedor, la idea sería que estas queden por encima, he intentado con Z-index y otras propiedades y aún no consigo que estas queden por encima del contenedor sin cortarse al pasar el mouse, dejaré un código de ejemplo para que me entiendan un poco más.


a[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
}
a[data-tooltip]::before,
a[data-tooltip]::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.85;
}
a[data-tooltip]::before {
  /*
   * using data-tooltip instead of title so we 
   * don't have the real tooltip overlapping
   */
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* we don't want the text to wrap */
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a[data-tooltip]::after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  content: '';
}

a[data-tooltip]:hover::before,
a[data-tooltip]:hover::after {
  display: block;
}

/** positioning **/

/* left tooltip */
a[data-tooltip][data-placement="left"]::before {
  top: -25%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
a[data-tooltip][data-placement="left"]::after {
  border-left-color: #000;
  border-right: none;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <style media="screen">
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700&display=swap');

*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body{
background: #0c7788;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 22px;
}

.wrapper{
width: 500px;
margin: 50px auto 0;
background: #fff;
padding: 30px 40px;
border-radius: 3px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.125);
}

.wrapper .title{
font-weight: 700;
margin-bottom: 15px;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: center;
}

.wrapper  ul{
  height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.wrapper  ul.active{
height: auto;
}

.wrapper  ul li{
margin-bottom: 5px;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
}

.wrapper  ul li:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: -12px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #bfbfbf;
}

.wrapper .toggle_btn{
margin-top: 15px;
font-weight: 700;
color: #ffffff;
cursor: pointer;
margin-left: 70%;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 5px;
background: rgb(204, 12, 79);
}

.wrapper .toggle_btn.active .fas{
transform: rotate(180deg);
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b99e675b6e.js"></script>

  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="title">Show More & Show Less Button </div>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#" data-tooltip="left tooltip" data-placement="left"><span class="tooltip-content">left tooltip</span></a> ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae necessitatibus consequatur quae doloribus eaque quod cumque? Modi, impedit, deserunt pariatur accusantium commodi magnam eos, qui debitis officiis obcaecati ut voluptatum.</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis, ex?</li>
          <li>Lorem, ipsum.</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis, ex?</li>
          <li>Lorem, ipsum.</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="toggle_btn">
          <span class="toggle_text">Show More</span> <span class="arrow">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(".toggle_btn").click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(".wrapper ul").toggleClass("active");

    if($(".toggle_btn").hasClass("active")){
      $(".toggle_text").text("Show Less");
    }
    else{
      $(".toggle_text").text("Show More");
    }
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>



Si me pudiesen ayudar u orientarme, estaría muy agradecido.

Tienes en el .wrapper ul un overflow:hidden por eso te lo oculta. Cámbialo por overflow-y:clip

Amigo muchísimas gracias, de todas las propiedades overflow, nunca pensé en clip, te agradezco un montón, saludos.
